# open ports or not? language problems

Tags: email, firewall, port, imap, smtp

community,

I do not really have a technical question but rather a comprehension one.
I try to set up my own mail server as a private project on a hetzner cloud server, using ubuntu 20.04
and their UFW. Therefore I am following a Tutorial on 'Tutorials24x7' (https://ubuntu.tutorials24x7.com/blog/install-mail-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-using-postfix-dovecot-and-roundcube).

Unfortunately english is not my mother tongue and so I ran into some understanding difficulties.
In the part 'prerequisites' it says:

*'Make sure that the ports 25 (SMTP), 587 (SMTP over TLS), 465 (SMTPS), 143 (IMAP), 993 (IMAPS), 110 (POP3), 995 (POP3S) are not-opened or closed using appropriate firewall tool.'*

I think the 'not-open or closed' puzzled me.

When it comes to opening or closing ports alarm bells start ringing in my head because I dont want to rush into security problems.

So here comes my question. I am not supposed to open all the ports, right? Rather than opening them, they are supposed to be closed, arent them?

Many thanks for helping me out!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the same page, under the same paragraph it goes on to say

> the security group assigned to the instance must be updated to **close** these ports for external communication over the internet.

Emphasis is my own.

Comment: awesome, thank you very much for that quick answer